# Erro no composer: SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, composer, ssl

Eu encontrei alguns tópicos no SO em inglês mas não consegui resolver o problema por la.

Qualquer biblioteca, fw, qualquer coisa no caso que eu tente instalar com o composer, recebo esse erro de SSL.

## OBS: Eu tenho SSL instalado em localhost

Quando dou um require no symfony por exemplo, ele me retorna isso:

```
Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Alguém saberia resolver?

Obrigado!

Comment: Ta passando por algum firewall?

Comment: Acho que não, Lucas...